# Graph of a simple Category with an endomorphism

Tags: category-theory

Consider a category that has (at least) two objects $A$ and $B$, a morphism from $A$ to $B$, $f_{AB}$, and an endomorphism from $A$ to $A$, $g_{AA}\neq id_A$. Naively I would depict the graph for these objects and morphisms as

[image]

But this looks misleading because it looks as if the path
$$A \overset{id_A}{\to} A \overset{f_{AB}}{\to} B$$
turns out the same "result" as
$$A \overset{g_{AA}}{\to} A \overset{f_{AB}}{\to} B,$$
namely $B$. If we define the latter combination as $h_{AB} := f_{AB}\circ g_{AA}$ and add $h_{AB}$ as an arrow from $A$ to $B$, the situation gets even weirder.

As far as I understand the important bits are the paths as a whole, not where they end up, but this is not obvious from the graph. Is there a canonical better way to depict the situation in a graph such that more of the category theory specificities are obvious?

EDIT: Rephrasing the question to be more straight forward: If we have exactly $f_{AB}$ and $g_{AA}$, the necessary identity morphisms, and the combinations of these in the category, what is the graph (commutative diagram?) to depict it? Comments suggest to duplicate nodes in order to force a DAG?

Comment: If this is *all* of your category, so that $\mathcal{C}(A,B)=\{f_{AB}\}$, then being a category *requires* that $f_{AB}\circ g_{AA} = f_{AB}$, hence that it be equal to $f_{AB}\circ \mathrm{id}_A$. If you want it to be different, then you need to "picture" the parallel arrows. Not sure what you mean by "situation gets even weirder". If your category has "too many" morphisms, then you won't be able to "picture" it.

Comment: Note that even in "nice" categories, such as the category of all sets, you can have $f\circ g= f\circ h$ with $g\neq h$.

Comment: @Harald the question is not clear to me.  Are you saying, if the diagram is accompanied by the text "commutes", that certain arrows are then equal?   Because your diagram is not a DAG (there's a restrictive definition of commutative diagram which is just a functor $J \xrightarrow{F} C$ where $J$ is the skeleton and $C$ is your category, and $J$ is posetal.  Kind of limited.  I don't like it.  I think if your diagram indeed commuted, which it could possibly in some context, then what you get is a regular language $L$ of "strings" $f_1 \circ f_2 \circ \cdots f_n$" that when interpreted as...

Comment: ... morphisms are equal.  I am liking this definition more than the usual one.  It's as if between any two start/end nodes you have an automaton with start node the paths' domain, and end node the language-accepting paths' codomain.  This is neat because regular expressions (languages) are proflific in programmers' toolboxes.  So you can even intersect two regexes.  Should the intersection be non-empty, then the union of both regexes is a set of equal morphisms.

Comment: If you don't like the idea of having an infinite set of equal compositions of morphisms, or that doesn't work for your application (simply because the generated equalities are not true here) then what you do is duplicate nodes so that your final graph shape is a DAG preferably without multi-edges.

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack I bent my question a bit  in the hope that an answer also answers my original question which I don't know how to make clearer. But if the answer includes duplicating nodes and force a DAG, that indeed would cover my original problem.:-)

Comment: @Harald You probably want a directed, acyclic graph (DAG) as a diagram.  If that is not possible, then consider generalizing.  See below answer =)

Answer (score 1):

Let $F: J \to C$ be your diagram, where the category $J$ may be any (usually finite) category.  $C$ is the ambient category where your diagram resides.  So your diagram is essentially just a functor from $J$ into $C$.

Any time you have a nodal self-loop, go ahead and duplicate the node and draw an arrrow from one node to the other matching the loop label.

If you have more than that, i.e. if you have loops back to a previous node that is not the current node, in a sequence of arrows.  Then what you have is essentially an automaton between any two nodes that defines the "language" of compositions that are to be equal, should this diagram be asserted or proved to commute.  I don't think that any such diagram can be converted into a DAG version (that's when $J$ is a posetal category).  Therefore, I recommend that, at least in your own work, generalize the usual definition of commutative diagram to be a functor from $J \to C$ where $J$ is not necessarily posetal.  It can be any category.